# Ionic2 - Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

The Error:

> Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http

And well, I do have a provider for HTTP, all registered.
Any idea where I can look to debut this issue?

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule, ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler} from 'ionic-angular';
import {MyApp} from './app.component';

import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import {GoldServiceProvider} from '../providers/gold-service/gold-service';

// ...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        // ...
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        // ...
    ],
    providers: [
        GoldServiceProvider,
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {
            provide: ErrorHandler,
            useClass: IonicErrorHandler
        },
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**gold-service.ts: My Provider Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class GoldServiceProvider {
    ...    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providers have Http included by default, and in order to use Http in your app you will need to add the `HttpModule` to your `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
...
```